# Why is Nightfly Color Scheme not Applying Properly in Neovim on macOS?

Tags: neovim

While working with Neovim on macOS, I encountered the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/oguzyildirim/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/_meta.lua:0: E474: Invalid argument
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_set_option_value'
        vim/_meta.lua: in function '_set'
        vim/_meta.lua: in function '__newindex'
        /Users/oguzyildirim/.config/nvim/lua/oguz/core/options.lua:26: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /Users/oguzyildirim/.config/nvim/init.lua:2: in main chunk
E5422: Conflicting configs: "/Users/oguzyildirim/.config/nvim/init.lua" "/Users/oguzyildirim/.config/nvim/init.vim"
```

I had encountered this error before, but it resolved itself after some time. However, it seems that the Nightfly color scheme is not working.

My colorscheme.lua file looks like this:

```
local status, _ = pcall(vim.cmd, 'colorscheme nightfly')
if not status then
  print('Colorscheme not found!')
  return
end
```

And my options.lua file looks like this:

```
local opt = vim.opt -- for conciseness

-- line numbers
opt.relativenumber = true
opt.number = true

-- tabs & indentation
opt.tabstop = 2
opt.shiftwidth = 2
opt.expandtab = true
opt.autoindent = true

-- line wrapping
opt.wrap = false

-- search settings
opt.ignorecase = true
opt.smartcase = true

-- cursor line
opt.cursorline = true

-- apperance
opt. termguicolors = true
opt.background ="dark"
opt.signcolumn = "yes"

-- backspace
opt.backspace = 'indent,eol,start'

-- clipboard
opt.clipboard:append('unnamedplus')

-- split windows
opt.splitright = true
opt.splitbelow = true

opt.iskeyword:append('-')
```

In my plugins-setup.lua file:

```
local ensure_packer = function()
  local fn = vim.fn
  local install_path = fn.stdpath('data')..'/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim'
  if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then
    fn.system({'git', 'clone', '--depth', '1', 'https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim', install_path})
    vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]
    return true
  end
  return false
end
local packer_bootstrap = ensure_packer()

-- Autocommand that reloads neovim whenever you save this file
vim.cmd([[
  augroup packer_user_config
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost plugins.lua source <afile> | PackerCompile
  augroup end
]])

local status, packer = pcall(require, 'packer')
if not status then
  return
end

return packer.startup(function(use)
  use("wbthomason/packer.nvim")

  use("bluz71/vim-nightfly-guicolors") -- oreferred colorscheme




  if packer_bootstrap then
    require('packer').sync()
  end
end)
```

And my init.lua file:

```
require('oguz.plugins-setup')
require('oguz.core.options')
require('oguz.core.keymaps')
require('oguz.core.colorscheme')
```

If you need more information to help me resolve this issue, please let me know.

Comment: apparently you have init.vim and init.lua under your config dir. You can only have one if these as your config entry point.

Comment: @jdhao Yes, you are right. But the main source of the problem was that native mac terminal doesn't support color scheme. I installed zshrc for this. Also, using another terminal would be the safest way. Like iTerm.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The problem is that native mac terminal doesn't support color scheme. Download another terminal app for that. Like iTerm. I also recommend installing zshrc.